# what is Missing Required Whitespace error in connection string?

Tags: .net

```
<add name="SqlCon" connectionString="Data Source= LAPTOP-SIPO1KTL; Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog= Student;"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

i am getting an error on providerName saying Missing Whitespace Required.

can anyone suggest what i am doing wrong in this connection string?

Comment: I think you need an extra space before 'providerName'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss a white space before your `providerName` attribute. It should probably be

```xml
<add name="SqlCon" connectionString="Data Source= LAPTOP-SIPO1KTL; Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog= Student;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: thank you so much for this answer, but later i upload this question i saw that i missed a space before provider name. But thank you also